# two identical projects: one has unresolved externals, the other does not

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have two VS 2017 projects that, structurally, are identical.

They both:

- are compiled in Release x64
- are located in `project/folder/project1` and `project/folder/project2`
- import a specific library (that is causing the issue) in `my/library/here/`. This path is defined in the Project properties > C++ > General > Additional include directories
- their imports in `project1.h` and `project2.h` are as follows:

```
#pragma once

#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include "my_problem_library.pb.h"

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib" )

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "6000"
```

In project1, the code compiles without any issues. It uses the exact same functions from `my_problem_library` as project2, yet when I compile project2, I get these arrors:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl GameInfo::GameInformation::~GameInformation(void)" (??1GameInformation@GameInfo@@UEAA@XZ)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: __cdecl GameInfo::GameInformation::GameInformation(class google::protobuf::Arena *)" (??0GameInformation@GameInfo@@IEAA@PEAVArena@protobuf@google@@@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::LogFinisher::operator=(class google::protobuf::internal::LogMessage &)" (__imp_??4LogFinisher@internal@protobuf@google@@QEAAXAEAVLogMessage@123@@Z)
...
fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals
```

The functions causing these errors are all located in `my_problem_library.pb.h` (which was auto-generated, I might add).

Could there be another import that I missed? Why does this work on project1 but not project2?

All insight is gladly welcomed.

Comment: The `__declspec(dllimport) ...` error means its expecting you to link to an import library for a dll. So the problem would be what you added or did not add to the `Linker->Input-> Additional Dependencies`

Comment: You could do a diff (e.g. using BeyondCompare) of the project files to find out what the real differences are.

Comment: It seems you did not link against the library or libraries that has the actual code for GameInfo::GameInformation and LogFinisher::operator=(...).

Comment: @stackoverblown how do you mean? `my_problem_library.pb.h` contains the function headers etc

Comment: @drescherjm neither had any additional dependencies, so I added it to both to be sure - and that seems to have fixed the issue, thank you!

Comment: @JessicaChambers The header file usually has the function/class declarations, it does not have the actual code. The compiler or actually the linker needs the actual library to link against in order to build the final executable or library. The library is usually in the form of libraryname.lib which you add to the Additional Dependencies field in Visual Studio,